# Still can't resolve simple symbol after adding json-simple to classpath

Tags: java, json, import, classpath

So i need to use JsonParser from json-simple and even after adding the jar file to the CLASSPATH I can't import org.json.simple because I still get cannot resolve symbol 'simple'. I don't know what to do at this point.

EDIT: Solved thanks to [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Two cases can be there:

1. The jar is not really in the classpath used by the java-instance.
2. Package name referenced can be incorrect.

If you have done above two correctly, then  provide some information on adding the jar in the classpath.

Comment: Luckily I've been able to solve it, thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?rq=1